# Node js requests to certain websites returns the diamond with question marks

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, parsing, request

I'm building node js html parser with 'request','request-promise' and 'cheerio'. But when I run these code in my linux environment of my Mac. Request with 'www.popsnowboard.co.kr' and 'www.amazon.com' is returning html with diamond with question marks.                                   const rp = require('request-promise');
    rp('https://www.amazon.com')
      .then(result => console.log(result);)                                    I heard this is some utf-8 encoding issue. But head meta tag in the both website included "utf-8 charset". Could anyone tell me what should I do to get the normal html?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please follow [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Add some code so that it shows what have you done and it becomes easy to debug code

Comment: That's likely because most websites are encrypted (https). The popsnowboard page is unencrypted but contains several Korean characters in the source, which will appear as the diamond symbols in a terminal if the chars are unsupported.

Comment: So amazon returns the encrypted result if we don't send request through the official browser such as Chrome? But I saw someone parsed Amazon, and even my parser works on amazon.uk. If most website are encrypted, how can we see the contents through Chrome or Safari?